# Ubuntu server - some one takes 6GB of RAM - how to determine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux: which process consumed all the memory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/165461/linux-which-process-consumed-all-the-memory)

After server restart i've got strange behaviour - someone takes ~6gb of RAM, usually after reboot i hab ~7gb of free RAM( according to top), now - only 1gb
Top shows nothing - no processes with higm mem consuption( only 4 processes with 120-150mb of RES memory).
How can i find out who consumes 6 GB of RAM?

**UPDATE:** Seems to be linux disk cache, but i cant understand why before i had ~5gb of free ram  after restart and now only 1gb. Seems to be really slow, when it comes to ~50mb of free ram, now big chunks are release by disc cache for applicaitons.

```
free -m 
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7995       7076        918          0         33       5639
-/+ buffers/cache:       1404       6590
Swap:         2053          0       2053
```

e

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        8187192 kB
MemFree:          835436 kB
Buffers:           33900 kB
Cached:          5774872 kB
SwapCached:           72 kB
Active:          5150276 kB
Inactive:        1910664 kB
Active(anon):    1026268 kB
Inactive(anon):   227048 kB
Active(file):    4124008 kB
Inactive(file):  1683616 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       2102456 kB
SwapFree:        2102384 kB
Dirty:              3804 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1252236 kB
Mapped:            20372 kB
Shmem:              1208 kB
Slab:              82260 kB
SReclaimable:      64720 kB
SUnreclaim:        17540 kB
KernelStack:        4136 kB
PageTables:        15552 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     6196052 kB
Committed_AS:    5874148 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      334272 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359398908 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        7680 kB
DirectMap2M:     8372224 kB
```

Comment: How did you check the memory usage? Can you paste the output to get a better help?

Comment: A 'cat /proc/meminfo' would help here.

Comment: and http://serverfault.com/questions/170618/why-is-there-no-free-memory-in-my-ubuntu-system

Comment: and http://serverfault.com/questions/67759/how-to-understand-the-memory-usage-and-load-average-in-linux-server

Answer (score 2):

http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: seems to be very close(i've attached free -m output to the original quetion), thanks! The only thing confuse me - there such behaviour was not seen before, previously i had ~5GB after restart